# Child elements preventing trigger event on parent

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent `<span>` element with nested `<em>` elements. The `<span>` is given a width and `display:block` via CSS.

The `<span>` has a jQuery trigger event on it which is fired correctly but if you rollover one of the child items then the mouse out event is fired and my Twitter Bootstrap popover disappears.

Is there a way to "hide" the child elements to prevent this from happening?

/*** UPDATE WITH CODE SAMPLE **/
Th stopPropagation() is not working.

```
$("#div").on('mouseover', '.badge', function () {


                //prevent child items from closing our popover
                $(this).on('mouseenter', 'em', function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                })

                $(this).popover({
                    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
                    title: 'Title',
                    content:"Some content",
                    html: true,
                    placement: 'auto',
                    trigger:'manual'
                });

                $(this).popover('show');

        });
```

Comment: If I am understanding your question you can directly check if the element is hidden either via `$(event.target).is('hidden')` or `$(this).is('hidden')` so that when these element are hidden the handlers will not fire. One the other hand if you called the hide function the element essentially has nothing to mouse over and shouldn't raise the event.

Comment: There are three ways to "hide" the child elements. 1. You provide some code so we can look at it and tell you how. 2. You figure out how by yourself. 3. They get scared and hide by themselves.

Comment: Hi CalebB, the child elements are never hidden. I just don't want them to register as DOM elements that the jQuery will recognize.

Comment: Can you post the entire code or share a link?

Comment: I think your best option is to post your current jquery/js code which will greatly assist us in helping resolve the problem. Beyond that you can add a class to the elements `ignore` which you can check for.

Answer (score 0):

As per the updated code, you don't need `event.stopPropagation()` to suppress events on child elements. You can make use of e.target to locate the element from where the event was triggered and make use of it to determine what should be the course of action.

```
$("#div").on('mouseover','.badge',function (e) {        
         if($(e.target).attr("class") == undefined) {  // since em doesn't have class attribute , this would return 'undefined'
              return true;
          }

           $(this).popover({
                template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
                title: 'Title',
                content:"Some content",
                html: true,
                placement: 'auto',
                trigger:'manual'
            });

            $(this).popover('show');            
    });
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/ao1L2Lce/2/

(P.S - I have replaced `mouseover` event with `click` in the fiddle for validating the functionality easily )

Comment: Just updated the original post with my sample code which doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: updated the solution. please see the new explaination.

Comment: thanks for the update, however it still didn't look like it was working correctly so I came up with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround, where I placed a transparent background span element over the top of the "badge" and placed the popover event on that.